# What is the difference between data.ArrayStore, data.JSONStore and data.xmlStore

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, xml, extjs

I worked last week on grid and had faced many problem. My simple question is 
Who would you explain difference between data.ArrayStore, data.JSONStore and data.xmlStore.

Comment: Every details with examples are provided in sencha docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all documented:

[`ArrayStore`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.data.ArrayStore.html):

> Small helper class to make creating `Ext.data.Store`s from Array data
>   easier. An `ArrayStore` will be automatically configured with a
>   **`Ext.data.reader.Array`**.

---

[`JsonStore`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.data.JsonStore.html):

> Small helper class to make creating `Ext.data.Store`s from JSON data
>   easier. A `JsonStore` will be automatically configured with a
>   **`Ext.data.reader.Json`**.

---

[`XmlStore`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.data.XmlStore.html):

> Small helper class to make creating `Ext.data.Store`s from XML data
>   easier. A `XmlStore` will be automatically configured with a
>   **`Ext.data.reader.Xml`**.